# read WebCacheV01.dat file in UWP App, but failed

Tags: uwp

I try to read WebCacheV01.dat file in my UWP App.

Code like this:

```
var filePath = "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat"; 
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);

if (file != null)
{
    IList<string> lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
}
```

But When I code running reach the line

```
IList<string> lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
```

It gives me an error message.

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
> process

It looks like the WebCacheV01.dat is used by another process and it makes my code can not read this file.
But I just want to do some read-only operation on this file. Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Which line throw exception?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please tell me where the exception happens?

Comment: The error happens when the code reach the line of IList<string> lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file); @RoyLi-MSFT

Comment: There is no other way to solve this unless finding out another process and finish it. It seems to be the data for browsing information and it might be used by the browser I think. Have you tried to close the browser and test this to see if another process means the browser?